# Telecommute being revoked

Tags: united-states, telecommute

I (along with everyone in my office) went to Telecommute in March 2020.

Our team was as productive  as in office (if not more so).

In March 2022, we were advised that because our company had built a new multi-million dollar facility they would soon be having people come back in.  I spoke to my immediate Vice President and he signed and approved (and it's show in my payroll online for work) that I was changed to full time telecommute March 22nd 2022.

As of February 1st 2023, the Senior VP (above him) has said that I along with a few others need to begin coming back into office.

I moved an hour and a half away from the office when I was approved for full time telecommute. Some moved out of state and they are being allowed to continue their telecommute status. I have read the policy and it states that the only time telecommute can be revoked is if my performance review is poor or the job duties have changed. There is no mention as to a distance away from office to be approved for telecommute.

The VP that approved my telecommute status has apologized profusely that the Sr. VP is insiting that I return - he has been good enough to say I only need to travel into office 2 days a week, yet others do not.

Do I have any legal rights to dispute this order to return to office?

The main reason for return is to justify building this multi-million dollar facility that is only at about 25% occupancy.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145171/discussion-on-question-by-texasmama0616-telecommute-being-revoked); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 33):

Texas is an "at will" state.

So basically, they can do anything they want, suggest changes to your contract in any way they want, and they can fire you if you do not accept those changes. Unless you have *special* protection by law or explicit protection from that in your contract.

You have not listed anything that would grant you such a special protection, for example disabilities, or discrimination based on gender, religion or other protected classes.

They changed your contract once. They want to change it again. You don't have to accept it, but unless you negotiated something else, they do have the right to fire you for any reason, including "didn't sign the changed contract", at any time.

So basically, yes, they can do that. Other countries value worker protection more, the US values the employer's freedom more. Right now, you are at the receiving end of said "employer freedom".

Comment: Even in an "at-will" state, contracts cannot be changed, since they are signed documents by both parties that are enforceable by law.  A change to a contract would require both parties agreeing to it.  Do you mean instead that an offer letter, or work condition notice, can be changed at will?

Comment: No, I mean they can just give *another* contract and tell you to take it or leave the premises for good. The fact that you had a contract valid until this minute means exactly nothing, since they can just terminate it, literally... "at will". So yes, technically, they cannot "change your contract". They can only terminate it and offer you a changed contract if you prefer to stay employed.

Comment: But again, a contract would state conditions that would allow for termination, as well as a period of time that the contract is enforced.  A contract cannot be just torn up by one party without there being a set of consequences attached to it.  If there was a contract agreed to by both parties that said that the OP could telecommute, the employer cannot just change their mind without an agreement from the employee.  If there is an offer letter, though, that states that it is not an employment contract and can be changed, that would be different, but that is not a contract...

Comment: Yes, even under a contract, an employer can fire an employee for any reason, but unless the employee had done something that violated the contract, they would be entitled to the full value of the contract.

Comment: @BrianPlace - Only if that clause is in the contract.  Most "at-will" employees do not have an employment contract.

Comment: They changed the author's terms of employment at least once, back in 2020, indicating they would be telecommuting. Devil's Avocat: They are simply returning to their original terms. If the policy being applied to the author, is not being applied to certain employees, that is up to the company to resolve. Not every position or role is worth the same to the company.

Comment: "they would be entitled to the full value of the contract" which, if nothing else is specified, is exactly zero. I cannot speculate what *may be* in their employment contract. There is no legal minimum. Almost anything can be put into a contract. They might have been promised a red Ferrari with glitter and unicorn stickers upon getting terminated in their contract. Or maybe not. So my answer does not mention it.

Comment: @Donald You are right that the terms of employment are being changed, and have been before.  My point was simply that a contract, which is does not sound like the OP has, is a legal binding document between two parties that cannot be changed by one without the consent of the other.  Employment terms, such as through an offer letter, can be changed, but that is different than a contract.

Comment: @nvoigt You are correct that you cannot speculate what was in the contract, but that doesn't change what a contract is.  My point was only that a contract is legally binding document that cannot be changed by just one party, which is different than an employment agreement.  In an agreement, than either side can change their needs, and the other can choose whether or not to continue.  That's what seems to be happening in the OP's situation.  I just wanted to point out that if there was a contract, then no, the employer, even in "at-will", cannot just change it because they feel like it.

Comment: @nvoigt I actually agree with your basic premise, that this sounds like an "at-will" employment that can be changed by the employer at their discretion.  My only issue was with the use of the word "contract," which as a legally binding document would have a different set of results with the situation that the OP presented.  Being in an "at-will" state would not alter the enforcement of a contract by either party.

Comment: @BrianPlace Where I think you'd be right is if the contract specified a length, e.g. "employee can work from home until 2032". Otherwise it's like....I signed a contract that I would rent your house. The contract did not specify a duration. I can, therefore, stop renting your house at any time. We had a contract for the thing, but not the duration of the thing.

Comment: Just because a state is an at-will state does not mean companies do not need to adhere to conditions specified in contracts. The purpose of contracts is to give conditions beyond the minimum specified in law. If a company breaches a contract, they can be held to account. It is exactly wrong to say they can change a contract. They cannot. They can change whatever the contract allows them to change.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely any "contract" was involved, and the OP did not mention contract.

Comment: @BrianPlace even if there is a contract, work from home policies are usually part of the "employee handbook" which is an appendix to the contract that the company can change at will at any time, even without prior notice.

Comment: @HappyIdiot I am not debating whether or not a company would act in accordance with the law, or what the necessary actions would be.  My sole point is that contracts cannot be changed by only one party, that there are consequences of doing so, whether or not you wish to pursue those consequences.  To state that contracts can just be changed by one party is factually inaccurate.

Comment: @jwenting Agreed, policies within a handbook that are not specified in a contract can be changed by one party.  I've never disagreed with that statement.  My point was solely that a contract, a legal document agreed by two parties, cannot be changed by one party without the consent of the other.

Comment: Okay, I worded my answer less colloqiual and more technically correct, you can stop discussing word choices now.

Answer (score 12):

You have the approval for 100% telecommute in writing. I would contact the "Sr. VP" directly and present your case. If the Vice President approving your telecommute is willing, bring him along as support.

I'm no lawyer and law questions are off-topic anyway. I don't know if the law helps you here. Better is always coming to a mutual agreement without the swinging the "lawyer-club". Is a two day office, three day homeoffice agreement working for you? If not, what is a compromise you would accept?

In the end it's a negotiation, the same like for a salary or benefits. Tell them why you need the telecommute "benefit", how it improves your work efficiency, and then decide if you can settle for their offer. If not, you'll need to go job hunting.

Comment: +1 for "It's a negotiation", and the ultimate choice being whether you can reach an agreement that works for you or want to throw the job-hunting dice again.  Just remember that fairness doesn't even begin to enter the equation, and "but she is still working remotely" is a losing argument.

Comment: This seems unlikely to go well unless OP is only at most two levels below the Senior VP.

Comment: Agreed. The only way you can get someone to override a manager is by going up the chain. But the higher you go, the less likely they are to say anything but "why are you wasting my time?"

Answer (score 3):

TL;;DR: No.

Companies can change policy at any time. If it isn't written into your *contract* that you will always be working remotely, no legally enforceable promise has been made. If you are in a protected class you may be able to ask for "reasonable accommodations"; not otherwise.

Yes, they can do this on a task or department basis. Or individual basis. Or by management's whim.

You can always ask management for permission to continue working remotely. They are under no obligation to agree.

Remote work goes in and out of fashion. There's currently a swing back as COVID restrictions ease. Either find a way to make it work for you, or try to find one of the decreasing number of jobs that can be done remotely, or try to find something with a commute you can tolerate.

Comment: I understand that people don't like this answer. Unfortunately that doesn't change the facts. If you have a better way to handle this, feel free to post your own answer for folks to vote on, or to tell me what your concern is so I can try to address it.

Comment: I have not voted, but the OP said the change was written down and entered into the system. I would assume that makes it a contract amendment. Doesn't matter though, as contracts in at-will states seem to be more of a guideline than anything of legal importance. After all, what is a contract worth that can be cancelled by either side at any time.

Comment: Contract amendment requires both parties sign; preventing unilateral changes is what a contract is for.  Granted, a contract may not prevent change either, but without it there is no legal basis to object upon, which was the actual question being asked. A written promise is only as good as the authority of its author.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Why? The higher up person could just say "accept this change to your current contract or be fired effective immediate". There is nothing in the old contract that would prevent that, as far as we know.

Comment: An employer cannot change the terms of an employment contract arbitrarily, even if it's an implied contract formed by practice. Of course that doesn't change the fact that the employer can terminate the employee for any reason, including not agreeing to change the contract.

Comment: In the US, implied contract is damned hard to enforce ... and you really don't want to have to go to court against your employer in any case; that tends to be a Career Limiting Action. I stand by my answer.

Comment: The contract probably says nothing about remote work. And the assumed default would probably be on-site (or on customer site, or at other assigned location), given the history of work. And permission to work from home has historically been viewed as a luxury, not a right, the past few years notwithstanding; many managers still see it that way, even for folks who have demonstrated high productivity in this mode. And site managers historically want to see Seats In Seats.

Comment: Most "at-will" employees don't actually have a written employment contract.  The VP saying they approve an employee telecommuting temporarily, does not imply a new contract was drafted.  Besides, the author's "contract" was changed once already, to mandate the telecommuting in the first place.

Comment: That brings us back to: Was the contract changed, or policy changed? Or did it exist at all? And what is the assumed default if unstated?

Comment: @keshlam You are correct in making a clear distinction between what a contract is, and what a policy change is.